# How to set fastcgi_busy_buffers_size correctly?

Tags: nginx

I am run few wordpress websites on single VPS server.

and i saw `[emerg] "fastcgi_busy_buffers_size" must be less than the size of all "fastcgi_buffers" minus one buffer in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:112"` error when i checked nginx -t.

I am put fastcgi_buffers size as below each on server block.

```
fastcgi_buffers 64 16k; # default 8 4k
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
```

and i tested fastcgi_busy_buffers_size as `28 ~ 32k`  on nginx.conf.

But no matter what i put it, i  can't find the same value.

Nginx keep getting the error below:

```
 [emerg] "fastcgi_busy_buffers_size" must be less than the size of all "fastcgi_buffers" minus one buffer in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:112

 [emerg] "fastcgi_busy_buffers_size" must be equal to or greater than the maximum of the value of "fastcgi_buffer_size" and one of the "fastcgi_buffers" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:112
```

Can some one please let me know if there is a way to set the correct fastcgi_busy_buffers_size value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> [emerg] "fastcgi_busy_buffers_size" must be less than the size of all "fastcgi_buffers" minus one buffer in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:112
> [emerg] "fastcgi_busy_buffers_size" must be equal to or greater than the maximum of the value of "fastcgi_buffer_size" and one of the "fastcgi_buffers" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:112
> ```

`fastcgi_buffer_size` rules how much memory will be allocated per FastCGI requests to accomodate its first stream of response, usually FastCGI response header. After this buffer is full, FastCGI buffer will shift to whatever allocated by `fastcgi_buffers`.

`fastcgi_buffers` rules how many blocks of memory, and its size, to be used to buffer the rest of the response, per requests.

`fastcgi_busy_buffers_size` rules how much memory can be actively sending responses to clients, and this value is bound to `fastcgi_buffers` and `fastcgi_buffer_size`, in which it should be:

- equal to or greater than the maximum value between `fastcgi_buffer_size` and one `fastcgi_buffers` block (minimum busy buffer to send FastCGI response to the client)

  ```
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size >= max(fastcgi_buffer_size, fastcgi_buffers[size])
  ```
- less than all `fastcgi_buffers` minus one (still to send FastCGI response data to the client, but you'll need to leave some blocks of `fastcgi_buffers` to accommodate writes for upstream responses)

  ```
  fastcgi_busy_buffers_size < (fastcgi_buffers[count] - 1) * fastcgi_buffers[size]
  ```

Using your configuration:

> ```
> fastcgi_buffers 64 16k; # default 8 4k
> fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
> ```

your `fastcgi_busy_buffers_size` should be between `max(32k, 16k) = 32k` (inclusive) up to `(64 - 1) * 16k = 1008k` (exclusive).

Furthermore, you'd probably want to align your buffers to your OS' page size to optimize your memory usage and avoid fragmentation.

Comment: This doesn't make sense? "`fastcgi_busy_buffers_size`[...]should be: **at least** equal to `fastcgi_buffer_size` + one `fastcgi_buffers` block (to send FastCGI response header + a portion of FastCGI response body to the client)", but the error says ""fastcgi_busy_buffers_size" must be **less than** the size of all "fastcgi_buffers" minus one buffer" (emphasis mine)